# Bibliotecas específicas e padrões dos compiladores de C em Windows e Linux

Tags: c, c++, linux, windows, biblioteca

Eu gostaria de saber o porque a conio.h e o `strrev()` da biblioteca `string.h`, não há no Linux.

Existe mais alguma que só é possível ser feito no Windows? E porque isso acontece?

Existe alguma que só é possível fazer no Linux?

Eu fiz algumas pesquisas, mas na maioria dos casos achei respostas muito superficiais.

Comment: Existem bastantes mais que são só especificas de linux/unix, e outras tantas que são só especificas de windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não existe no Windows também. Isso não é específico de plataforma, é de implementação do C, ou seja, o compilador tem uma biblioteca padrão que não implementa esta API.

Há uma especificação do que a linguagem C tem, e as implementações deve segui-la para poder ser chamada de C. Então o compilador deve ter uma biblioteca padrão que se conforme com a especificação. É verdade que, de forma geral, não proíbe ter nada a mais, e `conio` é algo a mais. Mas geralmente os compiladores não colocam coisas a mais, a não ser que sejam muito úteis, e muito bem implementadas, oque na prática acabará forçando entrar em uma versão nova da especificação. Se não entra é porque não deveria ter.

De fato a `conio` é muito ruim e não deve ser usada. Foi incluída em um compilador que queria ter diferencial e seguido por alguns outros, mas os que sobreviveram de forma sólida não fizeram isso.

Um bom compilador Windows como o VS-C++, o Clang, ou o MingW (GCC) não possui `conio`.

Existem diversas bibliotecas que só funcionam no Windows, ou só no Linux, ou só no MacOS, ou só no Android, etc. Até mesmo em distribuições diferentes do Linux ou outro Unix-like, ou uma variante do Windows, sem falar em versões diferentes.

Mas em geral estamos falando de APIs de plataforma e não padrão do C.

Se precisar de respostas mais aprofundadas faça perguntas mais específicas e mais detalhadas.

Answer (score 0):

A biblioteca `conio.h` e a função `strrev()` da biblioteca `string.h` não fazem parte do padrão `C`. Evite usá-las se o seu propósito é [portabilidade](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portabilidade_(inform%C3%A1tica)).

Uma implementação alternativa de `strrev()` pode ser algo como:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char * strrev( char * s )
{
    char ch = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int i = strlen(s) - 1;

    while( i > j )
    {
        ch = s[i];
        s[i] = s[j];
        s[j] = ch;
        i--;
        j++;
    }

    return s;
}

int main( void )
{
    char str[] = "O rato roeu a roupa do rei de Roma!";
    printf( "%s\n", strrev( str ) );
    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
!amoR ed ier od apuor a ueor otar O
```