# Quando usar esses comandos?

Tags: c

Quais são os critérios que eu uso para aplicar os comandos  `getch();` , o `return0;` e o `system("pause")` no final de um programa?

Comment: Recomendo nunca usar o `system("pause")` ele fará uma chamada para o sistema operacional e executará o comando `pause`

Comment: `return 0` indica para o sistema que o programa finalizou com sucesso

Answer (score 4):

**getch**

O `getch()` retorna a tecla que foi digitada pelo usuário, ele é comumente utilizado em menus com `switch`.

**return 0;**

O `return` é uma palavra reservada da sintaxe da linguagem `C` e de várias outras linguagens de programação. Quando criamos uma função, definimos qual será o tipo de dados que iremos retornar *(inteiro, decimal, texto, booleano, sem retorno)*, para retornar o valor nós utilizamos o comando `return` para retornar o valor que desejamos.

No seu caso você deve estar criando seus códigos dentro da função `main`, está mais ou menos assim:

```
int main()
{
    //Códigos...

    return 0;
}
```

Essa nossa função tem a seguinte assinatura:

`int` define o tipo de retorno da nossa função, nesse caso é um valor inteiro.

`main` é o nome da nossa função (podemos dar o nome que desejarmos).

`return` comando para retornarmos um valor. Conforme observado pelo @Denis, a função `main` retorna um valor inteiro para o sistema operacional e qualquer valor diferente de zero representa erro, por esse motivo retornamos zero para finalizarmos a aplicação com sucesso.

**system("pause")**

É a chamada de uma função que tem o objetivo de pausar a execução do nosso programa até a próxima ação do usuário.

Comment: Obs.: return com qualquer outro valor diferente de 0 na função main indica erro para o sistema operacional, `system("pause")` não é portável, funciona só no windows

Answer (score 1):

`getch` é uma função provinda da `conio.h`. Ela lê a tecla pressionada pelo usuário.
Um dia, `conio.h` pode até ter sido algo digno e mão na roda, mas [favor não usar mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/304271/64969).

`system` é uma chamada do sistema. Algo semelhante a rodar um comando no terminal. Seu próprio uso é um indício de que seu código tem uma parte dependente de SO (como notado pelo Denis Rudnei de Souza [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/344375/quando-usar-esses-comandos#comment693314_344375) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/344375/quando-usar-esses-comandos#comment693323_344378)). No caso, em sistemas Windows, há um comando chamado `pause`, que espera que o usuário tenha uma ação. [Leia mais](https://ss64.com/nt/pause.html).

`return` é o que o Pedro Paulo pôs em [sua resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/344378/64969). Só para dar algum detalhe a mais, veja uma lista de [códigos de erros comuns](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html) usados para saída do programa. Apenas note uma coisa: o código de saída do programa é usado para [uma forma específica de IPC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/214199/64969), só aceitando um único byte. Segundo [esse link](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html), o retorno na prática é dado como `% 256`, portanto como o byte menos significativo retornado.