# Instrução semelhante ao system("cls") em C

Tags: c

O Programa que estou fazendo funciona da seguinte forma: Sempre que um valor incorreto for digitado, quero que o programa avise que o valor está incorreto, e logo após limpe somente a mensagem de erro para que o usuário possa escrever um outro valor, porém a única instrução que conheço (`system("cls")`) limpa a tela completamente. Existe alguma instrução semelhante ao `system("cls")` em C, mas que limpe apenas uma certa parte da tela, e não a tela totalmente?

Comment: Na real, `system("cls")` não é garantido de limpar a tela. O que é a chamada `system`, da `stdlib`? É simplesmente uma delegação ao sistema operacional para chamar uma linha de comando do sistema operacional. Acontece que o comando `cls` no terminal do Windows faz com que o terminal fique com o prompt de escrita na parte superior. Então não é _algo do C_, mas de um programa externo que você está chamando. Assim como o `system("pause")` está chamando o programa `pause` do Windows

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Entendi. Valeu pelo esclarecimento, mas você conhece algum comando para limpar apenas uma parte da tela? Ou algum comando do próprio C que faça coisa semelhante?

Comment: Você teria de usar funções da biblioteca conio.h para manipular a tela de forma mais elaborada no MS-DOS/WIndows. No UNIX seria a biblioteca ncurses.

Comment: Resumindo o que o Jeff quis dizer, não é possivel afirmar que algo irá funcionar, sendo em C ou fora dele, depende do sistema e volta e meia de configurações, mas se tratando de algo simples a minha sugestão seria copiar o "output" (o que deve ser feito antes de enviar para o output real), limpar tudo, pegar o que foi copiado, manipular e limpar a área desejada por sua conta e depois jogar novamente, causando a impressão de que foi limpo só parte, mas na verdade foi "redesenhado". Mas é só uma sugestão, deve ter alguma g̶a̶m̶i̶b̶a̶r̶r̶a̶  lib que faça algo assim.

Comment: @epx, não curto a `conio`, e também não teve muita gente que curtiu https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/304271/64969

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Consegui resolver com a manipulação que você indicou, e algumas gambiarras a mais, mas funcionou. Porém consegui resolver porque o problema era no começo do código, se fosse no meio ou no final não iria resolver, então sua dica me ajudou em partes. Eu precisava de algum comando que realmente limpasse só parte do código, sem todas essas gambiarras  de repetir o código todo, para que pareça que limpou somente uma parte, que é eu fiz aqui.

Answer (score 1):

Tem a biblioteca windows.h, Você edita os pixel usando a função:

```
void gotoxy(int x,int y){// muda a posição do cursor
    COORD p={x,y};
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),p);
}
```

podendo usar um comando for para criar ou apagar:

```
for(x=0;x<60;x++){//Cria um quadrado
    for(y=0;y<30;y++)
        if(y==0 || x==0 || y==29 || x==59 ){
        gotoxy(x,y);//função para mudar a posição do cursor
        printf("%c",219);//imprime um character no console
        }
```

Para apagar é só você colocar a função gotoxy com x e y no lugar desejado e adicionar um:

```
printf("%c",32);//valor 32 = espaço na tabela ascii
```